# How to print Jasper reports from servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, web, printing, jasper-reports

I am trying to print a Jasper report from my web application's servlet. Below is the code which calls the printing function.

```
//Print the report
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("companyName",userBean.getCompanyName().trim());
                params.put("companyPhone",userBean.getPhone().trim());
                params.put("patientName",demographicsBean.get(0).getfName()+" "+demographicsBean.get(0).getmName()+" "+demographicsBean.get(0).getlName());
                params.put("patientAge",String.valueOf(demographicsBean.get(0).getDob()));
                params.put("address",demographicsBean.get(0).getAdrLine1()+" "+demographicsBean.get(0).getAdrLine2());
                java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(); 
                params.put("date",String.valueOf(new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())));
                params.put("doctorName",subUserBean.getFirstName()+" "+subUserBean.getLastName());
                params.put("drugName",drug);
                params.put("ptInstructions",ptInstructionsTxt);
                params.put("quantity",request.getParameter("quantityTxt"));
                params.put("refills",refilTxt);

                  Connection connection = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection();

                ReportConnector r = new ReportImpl();                
                r.printReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ReportResources/Prescription2.jasper"), params,connection);
```

Below is the code printing the report.

```
public void printReport(InputStream path, Map<String, Object> params, Connection con) throws JRException
    {
       JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(path, params, con);

       JasperPrintManager.printReport(jasperPrint, false);
    }
```

The issue is, eventhough this worked in localhost, nothing is getting printed (I do not have a printer now, but `MS One Note` should be open as the printer. That is happening in localhost).

what is wrong here?

Comment: Try leaving on the withPrintDialog flag and see if it shows anything useful.

Comment: Or try using JRPrintServiceExporter instead of JasperPrintManager. Example here http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533151/jasperprintmanagerprintreport-prints-3-copies

Comment: Just to get it straight - are you aware that this code will print out the report at the server side - not on the client (the browser side)?

Comment: @defectus : I wasn't, but later I did. How can I print this in client side?

Comment: Normally I'd let Jasper to generate a PDF and send it  to the browser as 'content-type' `application/pdf`. An example can be found here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html

Comment: @defectus : I tried it(not your tutorial), it ended up with duplicate header or page not found errors. Will try your one too.